# Odd redirect issue with Wordpress even though Headers are correct when missing trailing slash

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, http-headers, redirect-loop

Hey Fellow Programmers!

Ok real trivial I am sure but I just can't work this out.

Basically (when not logged in) and requesting a page without a trailing slash the browser returns

> "redirect loop"

error or in Firefox an alternative error but similar.

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
>   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
>       cookies.

Interestingly... When you do a simple refresh it loads fine and then it caches the 301 so works after.

Ok so here are the response headers:

> http://www.theurl.com/attitude-competition
>
> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Date: Mon, 28 Oct 2013 23:05:28 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.20
>   X-Pingback: http://www.theurl.com/xmlrpc.php Location:
>   http://www.theurl.com/attitude-competition/ Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   Content-Length: 0 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> http://www.theurl.com/attitude-competition/
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Mon, 28 Oct 2013 23:05:30 GMT Server:
>   Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.20 X-Pingback:
>   http://www.theurl.com/xmlrpc.php Link: ; rel=shortlink Vary:
>   Accept-Encoding Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=UTF-8

Everything looks OK to me, but I've tested in different browsers and it just fails each time.

**EDIT**

I have done some further research and here are the headers when logged in as admin which doesn't have the same issue.

> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Date: Tue, 29 Oct 2013 00:03:20 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.20
>   X-Pingback: http://www.theurl.com/xmlrpc.php Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984
>   05:00:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
>   Pragma: no-cache Location: http://www.theurl.com/attitude-competition/
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Encoding: gzip Content-Length: 20
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=15 Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=UTF-8

**EDIT 2**

Also even more oddly when Chromes Web Inspector is open it works fine. Can't be cache as I've tried incognito and other browsers.

Any ideas at all?

Comment: Are you 301 redirecting using .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Force Trailing Slash - Beau Bhavik Code START
<IfModule rewrite_module>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # If not a real file or directory.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  # Not a part of the WP admin area.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:^|/)wp\-admin(?:/|$)

  # If there is no trailing slash.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:.*)/$

  # Force a trailing slash on all virtual requests.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [QSA,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# Force Trailing Slash - Beau Bhavik Code END

# Force NO Trailing Slash - Beau Bhavik Code START
<IfModule rewrite_module>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # If not a real file or directory.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  # Not a part of the WP admin area.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:^|/)wp\-admin(?:/|$)

  # If there is a trailing slash.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?:.*)/$

  # Force NO trailing slash on all virtual requests.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# Force NO Trailing Slash - Beau Bhavik Code END
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check that you haven't got any conflicting rules with your server (such as .htaccess or nginx rules) where basically one is trying to correct the other and thus the infinite loop.

I'd also make sure your rewrite rules are OK - have you done anything funky with permalinks? Quick way to debug would be turn off permalinks or change the rule to a different one. May give some clues